# SOAP not fetches result in PHP for Mouzenidis travel

Tags: php, soap

I try to get results from http://api.mouzenidis-travel.com/search/ServiceMainSearch.svc?Wsdl

There is some methods to fetch data:

1. GetCountries // fetch available country data
2. GetCityDeparture(int countryID) //fetch available departure city data
3. GetFilter(int countryId, List departureCityId) // fetch others filters

---

// My PHP code:

$client  = new SoapClient("http://api.mouzenidis-travel.com/search/ServiceMainSearch.svc?Wsdl");

$countryList = $client->GetCountries(); // results below

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Code] => GR
        [ID] => 29
        [Name] => Ð“Ñ€ÐµÑ†Ð¸Ñ
        [NameLat] => Greece
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Code] => CZ
        [ID] => 6240
        [Name] => Ð§ÐµÑ…Ð¸Ñ
        [NameLat] => Czech Republic
    )
```

$cityDepObj = $client->GetCityDeparture(array('countryID'=>29));

```
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [Code] => MOW
    [GroupName] => Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ñ
    [GroupNameLat] => Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ñ
    [GroupOrder] => 4
    [ID] => 1
    [Name] =>  ÐœÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð°
    [NameLat] => Moscow
    [CountryID] => 460
    [IsDeparture] => 1
    [RegionID] => 0
)

[1] => stdClass Object
(
    [Code] => 
    [GroupName] => Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ñ
    [GroupNameLat] => Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ñ
    [GroupOrder] => 4
    [ID] => 299
    [Name] => ÐÑ€Ñ…Ð°Ð½Ð³ÐµÐ»ÑŒÑÐº
    [NameLat] => Arkhangelsk
    [CountryID] => 460
    [IsDeparture] => 1
    [RegionID] => 0
)
```

.
.
.

$client->GetFilter(array(29,array(1)));

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Client] No connections available ...
```

---

I wrote to the Mouzendinis Tech Support, no results.

What make I wrong?

Comment: People, do have somebody any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In C# this method requires field 'Country' as `int`, not an array of int. Also, other fields must be initialized as empty array or `null`.
The last field is a dictionary that caused filter update. For example: if you changed the city of departure, you should set the field to `DictionaryEnum.CityDeparture`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check their API documentation and check what parameters required to pass to GetFilter  method.

Answer (score 0):

as you made `$client->GetCityDeparture(array('countryID'=>29));`, did you try with `$client->GetFilter(array('countryId'=>29,'departureCityId'=>array(1)));` ?

otherwise, try a wsdl to php geneator that'll ease you the requests construction and handling the response